# How to avoid memory starvation in node.js?

Tags: node.js, performance, memory

When programming in node.js, the async programming model is a key aspect. In particular when handling streams of data, the API allows me to write/read data and then wait until the producer/consumer are ready for more data (via the pipe and drain pattern).
I am missing a similar concept for the availability of memory.

When writing a web server, this server can in principle handle an unlimited amount of connections concurrently (in the sense that each connection works on the input/output pipe asynchronously). However each connection also consumes a certain amount of memory. How can I throttle the acceptable amount of connections based on my available memory (without hardcoding an upper limit on the number of connections)?
I would have expected a mechanism that allows me to allocate memory via a method call and then wait for a callback to be invoked if that memory becomes available.

Is this doable somehow?
How do you manage memory starvation in node servers?

Cheers
Carsten

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7468792/1765851), it should cover most of your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I am not sure I see how this solves the issue:
- the article suggests to set an upper limit on the number of connections. But how would I select that limit? For usecases in which every request consumes more or less the same amount of memory, I could use a heuristic. But in the general case every request can have different memory requirements and the computation of a max connection limit UPFRONT does not seem to be feasible.

Comment: First of all, you haven't provided any issue, just a generic question which smells like premature optimization to me. As you probably already know, Node has a garbage collector and does not expose any API for memory management so there is literally no way of doing this in pure JS. And V8 is a JIT compiler so it's nearly impossible to estimate how much memory it will consume, as it gets smarter and more efficient over time (aka warmup).

Comment: It's really a question around how to design the application, rather than an optimization question. Since memory is a limited resource it seems to make sense to limit rate in which the app accepts requests depending on the current availability of memory.
Of course I am aware that node in GC based, but there might have been a way to get notified when memory gets released, to allow new requests to be accepted at that point. Similar to having a slow writer signal its availability via a "drain" event.

Comment: I understand your concern, but even if you wish to dynamically limit the amount of connections you accept in Node, the *only way* to do that is through the `maxConnections` option to any class that inherits from `net/Server`, because it tells the OS to drop connections before they come through to Node where allocations starts happening. You could look towards making a C++ module that inspects the heap before each request comes in, but then again, maybe Node isn't the best tool for your usecase.

Comment: The only thing I can think of for you is [node-gc-profiler](https://github.com/bretcope/node-gc-profiler) which exposes events for when GC occurs, but seeing as V8 may consume variable memory for the same code paths it won't help that much.

I recommend looking at a lower-level language which still has a GC but has a predictable and static memory footprint. My personal favorite is [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), but there's also [Go](https://golang.org/) which is more mature. Both of these exposes unsafe methods for manual memory management if needed.